# facebook marketing api, cant get draft campaigns, ads and adsets

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-business-sdk

I trying to build my develop environment to test the facebook marketing api.

I have created campaigns and adset and ads as drafts and when 
I Try to get it as draft I'am using this endpoint

```
act_xxxx/campaigns/?include_drafts=true
```

But I getting this error :

> ```
> "error": {
> "message": "(#100) Param include_drafts on field campaigns: This param is not valid",
> "type": "OAuthException",
> "code": 100,
> "fbtrace_id": "AdxtFrxBwJ0pCeYMxKHBkqC"   }
> ```

IN facebook doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/campaigns

There is available this parameter.

When I tried with the python SDK I'm getting the same error:

```
listEffectiveStatus = [
    Campaign.EffectiveStatus.paused,
    Campaign.EffectiveStatus.active,
    Campaign.EffectiveStatus.archived,
    Campaign.EffectiveStatus.in_process,
    Campaign.EffectiveStatus.with_issues
]
paramCamping = {
    'effective_status': listEffectiveStatus,
    'include_drafts': True,
    'use_employee_draft': True}

campaigns = my_account.get_campaigns(fields=fieldsCampaigns, params=paramCamping  )
```

Someone could help me with this problem? Or know some solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access all draft campaigns with the Facebook marketing API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058289/how-to-access-all-draft-campaigns-with-the-facebook-marketing-api)